# Make my Zopim chat script to open in new window

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my chat script for my website. It always open at bottom right of my web page. I want to make it open in new separate window.

```
function chat()
{
    window.$zopim||(function(d,s){
        var z = $zopim = function(c){
                z._.push(c)
            },
            $ = z.s = d.createElement(s),
            e = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        z.set = function(o){
            z.set._.push(o)
        };
        z._ = [];
        z.set._ = [];
        $.async = !0;
        $.setAttribute('charset','utf-8');
        $.src = '//v2.zopim.com/?1hwyxUI0W0lLoOIZZgBuVTfGzXIzNhGe';
        z.t =+ new Date;
        $.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)
    })(document,'script');
}
```

I'm new to scripting, can any one help me?

Comment: That's a third party plugin, you should contact Zopim support for this..

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found almost perfect one.

```
<a href="#" onclick="openWin()" >Live Chat Online</a>

<script>
function openWin()
{
var myWindow = window.open("https://v2.zopim.com/widget/popout.html?key=1hwyxUI0W0lLoOIZZgBuVTfGzXIzNhGe","","width=500,height=500");
}
</script>
```

Replace your **key=1hwyxUI0W0lLoOIZZgBuVTfGzXIzNhGe**, you can get it from the zopim generated code at this line

```
$.src = '//v2.zopim.com/?1hwyxUI0W0lLoOIZZgBuVTfGzXIzNhGe';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<a href="javascript:void($zopim.livechat.window.openPopout())">Open chat in new window</a>
```

[DEMO](http://api.zopim.com/files/meshim/widget/controllers/liveChatAPI/Window-js.html#%24zopim.livechat.window.openPopout)